# Make all the statements true

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

**Can you make all the below statements true with a single click? If yes, explain how.**

- Three + Eleven = Ten
- Seven + Five = Six
- Two + Four = Eight

**NB: 'A Single Click' means, with only a single left mouse button click. Not with a series of steps which includes only one mouse click action in it. Hope it's clear now.**

Comment: I clicked on the upvote button. Does that count? Are they all true now?

Comment: @Marius Now you are not allowed to answer.

Comment: As many users tend to answer your question by using keyboard instead of clicking to comply with "click only once", consider stating that it is not the way in you question (only click, not "do something, click once, do something").

Comment: @oleslaw Thank you. Updated the question.

Comment: I am simultaneously impressed and horrified.

Comment: I'm so tempted to change the formatting of those bullet points, using `*` instead of `-` maybe ;-)

Answer (score 115, accepted):

I can do this by simply

> clicking the "Edit" (or "improve this question" for those who are not logged in) link at the bottom.
>  The equations are written as:
>  - Three + Eleven = Ten (linebreak) - Seven + Five = Six (linebreak) - Two  + Four = Eight
>  Which is numerically equivalent to:
>  $- 3 + 11 = 10 - 7 + 5 = 6 - 2 + 4 = 8$
>  It is 8 between all the "="s

which is true :)

Comment: Perfect. correct  answer   :)

Comment: Took me a second to understand what you meant :S

Comment: @dcfyj Hope it looks clearer now

Comment: @oleslaw you are welcome friend. :)

Comment: Let me redirect you to this... https://xkcd.com/169/ In no context is a linebreak not understood as a separator. For this to be correct you still need to remove the linebreaks.

Comment: @MattTaylor: Well, not really.  C / C++ / Java / C# et al do not consider line breaks to be any different from spaces, and you can break a mathematical expression onto multiple lines like this one.  I think very long formulae in print are wrapped as well.

Comment: @oleslaw: Minor edit suggestion: For those reading P.SE without logging in, the "edit" button is shown as "improve this question".

Comment: @KeyboardWielder if anyone in my team at work wrote equations like the above in their code, I would have a serious talk with them about coding style guidelines. Wrapping long formula is also very different from line breaks after only 2 or 3 terms and operands.

Comment: @MattTaylo Bad coding style: Yes. Incorrect: No. Good coding style implies that things are obvious. Where's the fun in a riddle that's obvious?

Comment: I think we'll have to agree to disagree, as I also like my riddles to be unambiguously correct, as well as non-obvious. Hence the linked comic originally. Riddles that make people go "aargh, I'm annoyed I didn't see that, that's really clever" are what are going to make this site continue to thrive IMO

Comment: @MattTaylor Try `$- 3 + 11 = 10 EOL - 7 + 5 = 6 EOL - 2 + 4 = 8$` in TeX or LaTeX (I denote `EOL` the end of line).

Answer (score 36):

I can do it by

> Right-clicking under the question's title, so the menu covers all the statements that are not true. There are no statements below, so all of them are true.
>  [image]

Comment: Good thinking. But it doesn't make any of the statements true. It just hides the statements.

Comment: By doing that, there are no longer any statements to be seen, so "all" are true, because there are none.

Comment: @AeJey https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth

Comment: Yes, I agree. :)

Answer (score 16):

Ohforf, "mathematics lateral-thinking"? The answer is obviously

> "No." I leave proof of this fact as an excercise, since it's not required to answer the question (it says " If yes,").

Comment: The same answer was already given by Marius and he deleted it. You can make all those statements correct with just one click.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have an image editing program available, but:

> View the equations in photoshop with a draw line tool set to dashed line.  With your click, Draw a dashed line from the top right of the first equal sign to the bottom left of the last equal sign.  This turns the equal signs into inequalities, making all statements true.

EDIT: pretty much what @Lafexlos did

Comment: See @Lafexlos's answer

Answer (score 3):

I would

> click the edit button and correct the sums by navigating with arrow keys. But not sure if in the answer you intend for us to actually carry this out

Comment: Yeah, especially that you could navigate through the page elements via keyboar (do whatever you want without clicking at all)

Comment: I actually answered this way but I don't think this is a lateral-thinking answer and I deleted my own answer xD

Comment: You have to make the statements correct with just one click. Not with a series of steps including single click action.

Answer (score 2):

I do it with an single click..

> [image]

Explanation:

> I simply hover the correct equation on it.

Comment: Don't lie. We know how many clicks you needed to edit that picture :P

Comment: Explain how you did it. That's the part of the question.

Comment: Why did you use 18 in the 3rd statement?

Answer (score 1):

I just clicked here i.e.Your Answer...and below statements are true now...I have used Tab key and Enter key to post my answer..

Three + Eleven = Fourteen
Seven + Five = Twelve
Two + Four = Six

Answer (score 1):

Once click, watch me (in your mind)

> One click. watch me. I clicked edit. then Tab. then down down down, end backspace X3, F,O,R,T,E,E,N. down. backspace X3. T.W.E.L.V.E down backspace X5 S.I.X Tab, Tab, Write this text, Tab again and Enter.

Peer re-what? darn.

Comment: You have to make the statements correct with just one click. Not with a series of steps including single click action